# How to Modify HTML/JSX Based on Screen Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to change the text of a `<p>` tag based on the screen size. I see two ways to do it:

1. Create the text as:

```
<p> 
  <span className="one">text one</span>
  <span className="two">text two</span> 
</p>
```

And modify the CSS with media queries, for instance:

```
@media (max-width: 481px) {
  .one {
    display: none;
  }
  .two {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

The other use to use the actual React/JS inside the component:

```
let innerText;

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 481) {
    innerText = 'text one';
  } else {
    innerText = 'text two';
  }
}, [window.innerWidth]);

return (
  <p>{innerText}</p>
);
```

Which of these methods is more performant for this use case? Which is generally considered the best practice? Are there are methods that I have overlooked that are preferred? I'm concerned about using the React method as to not trigger hundreds of re-renders when I change the screen size, but I'm also concerned about unnecessarily rendering two spans.

Answer (score 0):

No need for CSS

```
const DEFAULT_MOBILE_BREAKPOINT = 1000;

export const useIsMobile = (breakpoint = DEFAULT_MOBILE_BREAKPOINT) => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.innerWidth < breakpoint);
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    onResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
  }, []);
  return isMobile;
};
```

You can reuse this hook for setting different elements/classes.

```
import {useIsMobile} from "../hooks/useIsMobile";



const App = () => {

  const text1 = "Hello World!"
  const text2 = "Goodbye World..."

  return (
    <body className={ useIsMobile(700) ? "dark" : "light" }>

      <p>{ useIsMobile() ?  text1 : text2 }</p>

    </body>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, that makes sense. However, doesn't useIsMobile just return the state? So if I use it in other files how will they know to re-render if I've changed the view to a mobile one.

Comment: The hooks state is independent. In the example above, the text will change at the default breakpoint of 1,000, whereas the body class will change at the argued breakpoint of 700. You may use this hook throughout the application as a truthy value to toggle what you need based on the current screen width.